# Hexagon map finding if some grids are surrounded algorithm

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple math game in hexagon geometry through Unity. It is not about Unity indeed.

I borrow the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do9zi.png) from https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/, to illustrate the problem, it is quite huge so I put it in the link.

---

**Background**

Same as tutorial in the link provided, I use an array for saving data, to simplify it, it is like:

```
[      0, 0, 0, 0,    
        0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0      ]
```

My aim is

> Check if one or more than one grids are surrounded by another type of grid.

Definition

> **Surrounded** means for a grid or group of connected grid, all neighbors are in different flag of them.

For example,

```
[      0, 1, 1, 0,    
        1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0       ]

//Should become

[      0, 1, 1, 0,    
        1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0       ]
```

It is pretty easy for this case I don't even need an algorithm, as I can create the grid with reference of its neighbor, like

```
class grid{
    grid[] neighbor;
    int flag; //0 or 1
}
```

So, when I need to check if a grid is surrounded, I just need to loop its `neighbor`.

---

**Problem**

However, this method become tedious in the following case

```
[      0, 1, 1, 1,     
        1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0       ]
```

So, I also need to check its neighbor's neighbor now, like

```
foreach (grid i in neighbor){
   bool is_surrounded = false;
   if (grid.flag == 1) {
       //Good
   } else {
       //Check its neighbor, if every neighbor except i is 1, then return True. 
   }
}
```

It is working fine for 2, but what if there is 3 blank grids. Recursion is not ok, as when a grid is not surrounded like

```
[      0, 1, 1, 1,     
        1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0       ]
```

I will then loop the whole map for checking around 8^n times.

---

**Question**

I think there is cleverer method I didn't realize, I welcome any kind/language of answer or even just an idea. For sure, I will bounty for working ans with explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to make strict definition - what region is called "surrounded". Perhaps possible approach is -  the cells without free way to outer map edge.

To check this way - use any simple traversal algorithm - for example, DFS (path finding algorithms look overkill here - they need final point)

Concerning recursion - you need to mark seen cells to avoid rechecking .There are [floodfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithms without recursion and with good complexity.

Comment: Thanks, I will test floodfill method. But my purpose is when the user click to change some grid, there will be an auto-filling, so I need to test the time-efficiency if it can handle the situation that user clicks really fast.

Comment: Note that flood fill  fills all the possible cells, while DFS tries to find possible path to border (single chain in the best case, branching bush in the worst). If you need filling - efficient FF algortihms work very fast for reasonable size grids.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this backwards. You coding logic looks fine but reverse the logic.

For each 1 in existence check around it for possible other 1's. If you return via any path of 1's (from) that first 1 (to) that first 1 then you have found a closed loop. Find the direction that the returning path came from to retun to the first 1 and then that is where the inside of the loop is. Then, if you are not interested in any deeper loops, mark all that are inside (both 1's and 0's) of that loop as removed from further searching. Complete the search and then after the search is done, and only after the search is done, mark all inside of the loops as 1's (if that is what you want). That way if you have loops beside of loops, then you will not be restarting over and over again.

For sub loops: Consider all 1's as a potential starting of a loop. If you return to any previous 1's then find which direction that came from (in it's return path) and consider that the inside of a loop.

When all this is done, and you have found the loops, then make your changes. Do not be concerned if the loops have zero inner positions as 0 is a valid size, simply make all possible insides of loops changed as you decide.

Thanks.

B Lean